# Using Code Snippets in Wordpress to remove a line of code from a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

I want to remove a specific line of code from a plugin in WordPress. I can edit the plugin itself, but when it is updated it overwrites the changes I have done. I read that using the code snippet WordPress plugin I can have it always overwrite, regardless of updates.

If the line of code I want to be removed is the 
    `'required'=>true` 
from the code below, how would I write that in the code snippet plugin? The plugin file I am editing is located at wp-store-locator/admin/class-metaboxes.php

```
`$meta_fields = array(
            __( 'Location', 'wpsl' ) => array(
                'address' => array(
                    'label'    => __( 'Address', 'wpsl' ),
                    'required' => true
                ),`
```

Thanks so much

Comment: your question is only related to the functional of Code Snippet plugin. you should ask this to their support. General computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.